# Solve the compound inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the compound inequality. And write the solution in interval notation.

$3v - 6 < 9$  or  $4v - 3 < -23$

I've reduced both down to:

$v < 5$  or  $v < -5$.

$(-∞,-5) ∪ (-∞,5)$

Is this correct?

Comment: That looks right- though are you sure you have the right inequalities to start with? It's an odd answer, since if $x<-5$, $x<5$, so you don't need both inequalities. Note that $(-\infty, -5) \cup (-\infty,5) = (-\infty, 5)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it looks great:
$$
3 v - 6 < 9 \Longleftrightarrow 3 v < 9 - (- 6) (= 15) \Longleftrightarrow v < \frac{15}{3} (= 5) \Longleftrightarrow v \in (- \infty , 5)
$$
and
$$
4 v - 3 < - 23 \Longleftrightarrow 4 v < - 23 - (- 3) (= - 20) \Longleftrightarrow v < \frac{- 20}{4} (= - 5) \Longleftrightarrow v \in (- \infty , - 5)\mbox{,}
$$
so
$$
3 v - 6 < 9 \quad \mbox{ or } \quad 4 v - 3 < - 23 \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad v \in (- \infty , 5) \cup (- \infty , - 5) = (- \infty , 5)\mbox{.}
$$